# Controlling multiple displays with debian

Tags: debian, gnome, xrandr, display

I have installed DEBIAN 7.8 in N2600 board. "http://www.jetway.com.tw/ru/ipcboard_view.asp?productid=939&proname=NF9C-2600/2800" .

On the installed system, we were trying to connect multiple displays (Monitor 1 - HDMI port) (Monitor 2 - CRT port). But, we do not see anyway to control the connected displays.

Say like : 
    Monitor 1 : To display a screen save application
    Monitor 2 : To display some video file.

```
I tried xrandr -q :: It shows only screen-0 it does not show HDMI or LVDS.
```

Need some procedures to debug.

Request some guidance.

Comment: On desktop hardware, the Xorg server detects all the GPUs in the system and loads drivers for them all, and detects any hot-plugged displays when they're plugged in.  Check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, and the kernel log (`dmesg`).  You're right that xrandr should show all the connectors, and the modes available / in use on them if they're not `disconnected`.

Comment: Just  probing the HW vendor on this..Waiting for their response.

Comment: On my laptop:  `$ xrandr | cut -f 1,2 -d' '
Screen 0:
VGA-0 disconnected
TV-0 disconnected
LVDS-0 connected
 
DVI-I-0 disconnected`.  Bleh, figured it would line wrap horribly.  But yeah, if you don't see "disconnected" outputs, they're not going to work when you plug things in.  You may need to boot with displays connected, IDK.  I haven't worked with Atom GPUs, but I do remember reading a while ago about bad open-source support for the GPUs on some of that stuff (embedded / SoC Atom systems).

Comment: @PeterCordes : "but I do remember reading a while ago about bad open-source support for the GPUs on some of that stuf"  If you can get me some link of that it would be much helpful..

Comment: I'm talking about back when those boards used video ASICs built on designs covered by patents / copyrights / trade-secrecy such that there was no documentation of how to program them.  If your board has actual Intel-brand GPUs that show up as "intel" in `lspci` output, you should be ok.  There were stories on the various binary-only-drivers from some manufacturers on http://phoronix.com/ back in like 2007 kind of era, I think.